# How can I include Polish letters in a validation regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have validation for first_name:

```
validates :first_name, :format => {:with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/}
```

Can somebody tell me how to add letters like:

ą,ż,ź,ć,ń,ł,ś,ę,ó, Ą,Ż,Ź,Ć,Ń,Ł,Ś,Ę,Ó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [Oniguruma character classes](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt). To verify that string consists of unicode letters, use `alpha` character class.

```
"abcÓ" =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]+\z/ # => 0
"abcÓ1" =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]+\z/ # => nil # contains digit
```

This, of course, will include not only said polish letters, but all unicode letters. Including japanese kana, for example (おにぐるま).